# How to find Leq for a WAV audio file like an SPL Meter would?

Tags: matlab, audio, real-time

Given an audio file (WAV), I need to find the $\rm L_{A_{eq}}$ (continuous A-weighted equivalent sound pressure level) of the audio file. For this purpose, I am following this workflow:

1. Get a frame of audio (say $0.125$ seconds of samples)
2. Scale the samples to find the $\rm SPL \ re \ 20 \ \mu Pa$ based on calibration factor obtained from a calibration tone.
3. Apply A weighting to the frame of audio data.
4. **For each frame** of audio data, find the SPL (dB) as:

$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{pressure}_{\rm Ref}    &= 20\times10^{-6};\\
\textrm{amplitude}_{\rm rms}  &= \sqrt{\rm mean( audData_1frame.^2 )};\\
\textrm{dBspl}_{\rm perFrame} &= 20\times \log_{10}\left(\frac{\rm amplitude_{rms}}{\rm pressure_{Ref }}\right);\\
\end{align}
$$

This gives the $\rm SPL \ re \ 20 \ \mu Pa$ of a frame of data. This would be the [Short $\rm L_{eq}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_level_meter#Short_Leq).

How do I proceed further to get these 3 quantities:

- $\rm L_{eq}$ = The total continuous equivalent sound pressure level. This wold be a scalar value for the entire audio file. If it has to be updated in a plot, how do we integrate the SPL of each frame with the previous frames?
- $\rm L_{eq_{fast}}$ = Sound pressure level with $125\ ms$ time weighting
- $\rm L_{eq_{slow}}$ = SPL with $1\ s$ time weighting

Comment: Note that A-weighting filter is loosely defined near 20 kHz, and bilinear transform warps the response, so it's probably best to oversample before filtering or use an equi-ripple type filter instead of BLT.  I have an accurate A-weighting filter based on standards here https://github.com/endolith/waveform_analysis/blob/master/waveform_analysis/weighting_filters/ABC_weighting.py

Comment: @endolith : Thanks for sharing the link. Currently, I am using the [weighting filters from MathWork's Audio System Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/examples/audio-weighting-filters.html) and they are giving pretty good initial results. I will test it out with your code too

Comment: Oh, I didn't know they had that.  Theirs should be fine, they're using the same tolerance limits as mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do we integrate the SPL of each frame with the previous frames?

You're measuring the RMS value of the (filtered) samples, which is `sqrt(average(samples^2))`, so if you're finding the RMS value in multiple chunks, it would just be `sqrt(weighted_average(chunk1^2, chunk2^2, chunk3^2, ...))` where the average is [weighted by the number of samples in each chunk](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95912/2206) (typically they are all the same length, but maybe a recording is not an exact multiple of chunk size, for instance).

To find the time weighting, the signal flow is:

1. Apply A-weighting filter
2. Square the samples
3. Apply a low-pass filter with a real pole at 1/τ (where τ is 125 ms or 1 s in your case)
4. Square root
5. 20*log10() of the signal to convert to dB

It's the same as the RMS of the weighted signal, above, except that instead of an unweighted average over the whole signal, you're using a sliding-time average (same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average I think).

The time-weighted SPL will be a signal, not a scalar for each frame.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked. I had to do some clever math because 
I'm calculating streaming LAeq values in real-time, but the sqrt(mean(frame1.^2, ..., frameN.^2)) gives me good results.

Can you point me to some theoretical background of using low-pass filter with a real pole at 1/τ for this purpose.

Comment: @ArnavMendiratta It's in the IEC 61672 standard (which happens to be identical to [Indian Standard 15575](https://archive.org/details/gov.in.is.15575.1.2005)), section 3.5
"time-weighted sound level" and 3.9
"time-average sound level"